# Shorten List's By Deleting Repetitions

Tags: python, list, append

I am making a function where it shortens a list by deleting the repetitive items. I have been fiddling with the code for a while now and whenever I get rid of one error, I get another. Any ideas?

```
def delete_adjacent():
    user_list = []
    list_length = int(input("How long do you want your list? "))
    check = 0
    characters = ""
    while len(user_list) != list_length:
        new_item = input("Input your item for the list: ")
        user_list.append(new_item)
    print (user_list)
    while check != list_length:
        item = user_list[check]
        count = user_list.count(item)
        if count == 1:
            check += 1
        while count > 1:
            user_list.remove(item)
    return
delete_adjacent()
```

Comment: You're not decrementing count after you remove an item in the `while count > 1:` loop.

Comment: You can also use the `set` command to remove duplicates from a list.

Comment: are you only  removing repeated sequences?

Comment: you removing adjacent repetation or any repetation

Answer (score 1):

Just use `set`

`set` is an object that acts like a `list` and has no duplicates.

```
user_list = list(set(user_list))
```

You can convert your `list` to `set` to get rid of the duplicates, then convert it back to `list` to not affect the flow of your code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to "figs" i found the easiest way to do it.

```
def delete_adjacent():
    user_list = []
    list_length = int(input("How long do you want your list? "))
    characters = ""
    while len(user_list) != list_length:
        new_item = input("Input your item for the list: ")
        user_list.append(new_item)
    print(set(user_list))
    return
delete_adjacent()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this:

```
>>> def remove_dup():
...     user_list = []
...     list_length = int(input("how long do you want your list? :"))
...     while len(user_list) < list_length:
...         item = input("enter a item: ")
...         if item != "" and item not in user_list:
...             user_list.append(item)
...         else: print "Either item was null or was already present in list"
...     return user_list
... 
>>> remove_dup()
how long do you want your list? :4
enter a item: 1
enter a item: 3
enter a item: 1
Either item was null or was already present in list
enter a item: 4
enter a item: 6
[1, 3, 4, 6]
```